# Edit ASP.NET Dynamic Data visibleTables Display Names?

Tags: asp.net, metadata, dynamic-data

I've figured out how to use metadata to define the displaynames for table data I want to rename - but I haven't figured out how to do this to the tables themselves - so that when the initial dynamic data menu comes up the menu options are friendly rather than the actual table names. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [TableNameAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.dynamicdata.tablenameattribute.aspx). It takes effect when you reference [MetaTable.DisplayName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.dynamicdata.metatable.displayname.aspx). The attribute can be applied either to the specific table class, or its associated [MetadataType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.metadatatypeattribute.aspx) class.